# Выравнивание гиперссылки

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Создал сайт на теме TwentyTwenty

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу фрагмент файла `header.php`

```html
                <div class="header-navigation-wrapper">
                        
                        <!-- <?php get_search_form( $echo = true ); ?> -->
                        
                            <div class="kCNgDb">
                                <span class="entrylink">
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/entry.php">
                                        <span class="eEkWAa">
                                            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/useentryicon.png">
                                            </img>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="gxtXIp"><?php echo " " ?>Вход</span>
                                        <span class="bidiEP">|</span>
                                        <span class="jCpPzc"> Регистрация</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        <?
```

а также файла стилей `styles.css`

```css
.kCNgDb {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.eEkWAa, .gxtXIp, .bidiEP, .jCpPzc {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.entrylink{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.header-main-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
    

.header-basket-wrapper {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Подскажите как добиться отображения гиперссылки `Вход Регистрация` вместе с иконкой в одну строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас внутри класса .entrylink - которым вы хотите задать выравнивание в строку дочерним элементам находится еще один элемент-контейнер , a внутри него уже находятся элементы которые вы хотите выровнять, поэтому и не работает. Чтобы исправить можно сделать, что то типо этого:

```
.entrylink a {
  display: flex;
}
```